# Angular Input mask for Binary numbers

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to build an input component which accepts only BINARY numbers from user. With a separator.

For example:
As user types, component should only accept 0/1 and append mask - after each binary digit.

[image]

I tried `PrimeNG` `p-inputMask` which does not accept regular expressions.

Also tried `NgxMaskModule`. But still no luck.

Are here any other plugins which would help?
Or Could I write a function by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function that will be filter your input values, ngx-mask does not have standard mask for Binary numbers. Probably you can write your custom pattern for mask, but it`s much more easy to write a function

Answer (score 0):

Check this with NGX

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask#patterns--character-string--pattern-regexp-optional-boolean

You can add your own patterns.
Usage:

```
<input type='text' [patterns]="customPatterns" mask="0-0-0-0" >
```

and in your component

```
public customPatterns = {'0': { pattern: new RegExp('\[0-1\]')}};
```

(for 1 and 0 only)

Check this cool tool for regex:

https://www.regextester.com/95029